# Edit file button on github is greyed out

Tags: github, github-classroom

[When I try to edit the file in a pull request by pressing the 3 dots , its just greyed out and i cannot click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrZAl.png)

Im trying to follow these instructions its for school hw.
[Instructions for school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1pMt.png)
Its a github classroom thing. "Select Edit file from the three dotted ... menu in the upper right corner of the file view on index.md." Is the step I am on and I do exactly as its saying yet if you refer to first screenshot the option is just greyed out.

Ive tried refreshing the page, googling the issue, havent found any solutions im just so confused.

Comment: are you sure you got permissions?

Comment: yes im sure I have permissions, this is the second assignment in the course and other students have completed the assignment